# How to resolve -W0104: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)

Tags: exception, testing, pytest, pylint

I am trying to test the error from `__getitem__()` function and getting the `Pylint` findings against it.

```
def test_check_error():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as error_i:
        obj["output"]    # getting error for this line
    assert str(error_i.value) == "abc"
```

but with that getting `"W0104: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)"`

Comment: What if you assign it to a value, e.g. `_ = obj.["output"]`?

Comment: @ MrBean Bremen, I assigned it to a variable like below, 
`xyz = obj["output"]`
but after that pylint says unused variable to `xyz`. Then need to add `print` statement which is not recommended.

Comment: If you use `_` as a variable name as proposed, pylint should understand that it shall not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the value, so it's a false positive for you, you should disable the message like this:

```
def test_check_error():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as error_i:
        obj["output"]  # pylint: disable=pointless-statement
    assert str(error_i.value) == "abc"
```